# In Weaviate, how to remove a property in existing class?

Tags: weaviate

The documentation on how to update an existing class to **add a new property** is clear in Weaviate documentation: https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/schema#add-a-property

However, what if I wanted to **remove a property** from an existing class. So for example, I have an existing Product class below, and I want to remove the `description` property - is this possible?

```
{
  "class": "Product",                    
  "vectorizer": "text2vec-transformers",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "product_id",                     
      "description": "Reference ID of the product",              
      "dataType": ["int"],
      "moduleConfig": {                     
        "text2vec-transformers": {
          "skip": true
        }
      }              
    },
    {
      "name": "name",                     
      "description": "Display name of product",              
      "dataType": ["string"],
      "moduleConfig": {                     
        "text2vec-transformers": {
          "skip": false,   
          "vectorizePropertyName": true
        }
      }              
    }, 
    {
      "name": "description",                 
      "description": "The description of the product",          
      "dataType": ["string"],
      "moduleConfig": {                     
        "text2vec-transformers": {
          "skip": false,                     
          "vectorizePropertyName": true
        }
      }             
    }
  ]
}
```

and we already have existing data so it will be great if I will not go in removing the class and recreating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is no direct endpoint that will allow you to remove a property from all objects of a class, it's possible to use [`PATCH` with the `objects` endpoint](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/rest/objects#update-a-data-object) to replace the the properties of a given object with the initial object except the property you want removed. Using the Python client, this becomes:

```py
def del_prop(uuid: str, prop_name: str, class_name: str) -> None:
    object_data = client.data_object.get(uuid, class_name=class_name)
    if prop_name in object_data["properties"]:
        del object_data["properties"][prop_name]
    client.data_object.replace(object_data["properties"], class_name, uuid)
```

If you'd like for Weaviate to natively support this feature, please [vote for it](https://github.com/weaviate/weaviate/issues/2848).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no API to remove a property from a collection. But you can replace the object as explained in [hsm207 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177363/8547757). Here is how to do it with the v4 Python API.

```py
my_collections = client.collections.get("Product") # Replace with your collection name
prop_to_remove = "description" # Replace with the property name you want to remove
for obj in my_collections.iterator():
    if prop_to_remove in obj.properties:
        del obj.properties[prop_to_remove]
    my_collections.data.replace(uuid=obj.uuid, properties=obj.properties)
```